# IntelliJ and SVN: "no changes detected" upon commit

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea

I'm trying to share a project between my desktop and laptop using Subversion. The project has 3 modules. I've imported the project folder into a repository in a shared folder that my laptop can access over the network.

I checked the project out on my laptop and then tried to open the project. None of the modules are visible, only the project's .iml file, as in the screenshot below.

I notice that the .iml file has a line for "content url", which refers to a location on my desktop. Maybe this is the problem. What can I do about it? Do I have to create a new project on the laptop and import the modules - so there would be 2 different top level .iml files, one for the desktop and one for the laptop? Am I going about this the wrong way?

[image: intelliJ]

**UPDATE**: The problem seems to be with committing. When I make a change in a file, save, and hit Commit Changes, I get a popup saying "No changes detected". This is the same on both laptop and desktop, and meant that I downloaded the wrong version onto my laptop before. I deleted the repository and created a new one, and my project works on my laptop now, but I can't commit changes from within IntelliJ (only with TortoiseSVN via file manager). Also, when I imported my project into version control from my desktop computer, the working copy wasn't put under version control. So I can't update from my desktop unless I check it out to a different folder.

I think there is something wrong with the SVN plugin with this version of IntelliJ (10.5.1). Does anyone else have problems with committing changes?

**RESOLUTION** I needed to
1) Update Settings | Version Control  to map Subversion to the working directory
2) Import into Version Control
3) Check it out again

It may possibly have been caused by the fact that the modules were originally standalone projects which were in separate repositories. Whatever the cause, IntelliJ's "No changes detected" dialog isn't the most helpful.

Comment: are you sure you committed all the files from the first computer? what does svn log show?

Comment: @matt I think so... I click commit on the desktop and it says there are no changes, and all the files are there on the laptop. I think it's this .iml file as shown in the screenshot, which contains the wrong content url. But I don't want to change it because when I commit it'll be copied to my desktop then presumably the project won't work there

Comment: You can check if you have commited everything using an external svn client like tortoise SVN (in windows) it will colorize all the files under version control

Comment: After performing the initial import you need to do a checkout in order to use version control in IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder OK, nice to know. I may be wrong but I thought I'd imported into Subversion with other projects in the past and didn't have to explicitly check out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please [refer to the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1186).

As for the content root, make sure that it's located under the project root or module root, in this case the path will be stored relatively to the project/modile root inside the iml file. If the fixed system specific path is used in the iml, such module will not work on other systems.

**UPDATE**:
Make an explicit mapping between the actual working directory and Subversion in Settings | Version Control dialog. If you are using the default  placeholder and your project files are not under the checkout root, it could be the case.

After performing the initial import you need to do a checkout in order to use version control in IDEA.

Comment: I already did. Unfortunately this document says next to nothing.

Comment: So, you've committed .idea directory and all the .iml files?

Comment: See update above. I can't commit from with IntelliJ for some reason.

Comment: Make an explicit mapping between the actual working directory and Subversion in Settings | Version Control dialog. If you are using the default <Project Root> placeholder and your project files are not under the checkout root, it could be the case.

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick (after then creating a new repository and checking it out into a different folder)

Answer (score 24):

VCS -> Refresh File Status solved this for me, when Intellij suddenly stopped noticing changes.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes doing `VCS -> Refresh File Status` works for me.

Other times, it does nothing.

A solution is to

1. COPY all your file contents to clipboard / external notepad (for backup)
2. Choose Rollback on the file which needs updating. Now it is up-to-date with the server and does not contain your new changes.
3. Edit file again (checkout), and PASTE your original file contents.
4. Attempt to commit changes. It should detect them now.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this today- checked out an existing project and had to update the SVN scheme from 1.6 (I think) to 1.8. That seemed to make Subversion not recognize that it was wrong it its belief- even though I could DIFF and see changes relative to the latest repository version- that "No Changes Detected."

I got so fed up that I shut down Intellij...on a whim I reopened it, and the file in question appeared blue...hmmm...yep, now it detected the changes.

[image: Thanks, Roy!]

Comment: I just gave up with Subversion and started using git instead!

Comment: I had the same issue with the git plugin after switching from WebStorm to IntelliJ. Fiddling with the settings (without changing anything) and restarting IntelliJ did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I got into the similar issue today and I tried `VCS -> Refresh File Status`, but it didn't help me. When i looked at `Version Control->Subversion Working Copies Information`, i found an svn error `The working copy at /home/project is too old to work with svn client 1.9.4`. First i ran `svn upgrade` and then doing `VCS -> Refresh File Status` resolved my issue and i was able to commit my changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue it seems it may have been caused by having a file with the same name in two different GIT-repositories.

I was able to fix it by opening File -> Settings -> Version Control and then un-assigning and re-assigning GIT as the VCS of the two directories which both had the file. First the directory in which there was no changes in the file then the other active one which did have changes (but which did not detect them before).

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions here helped me.

Ended up checking out the entire repository again, copied all the sub folders over to the newly checked out folder and submitted the changes.

Deleted the old folder and renamed the new folder to the old folders name.